# Adding to a dictionary in python instead of appending

Tags: python, dictionary

My raw data is:

```
abc 123
abc 456
def 789
def 101112
```

I want to put this into a dictionary where the first column is the key and the second column is the value. In the dictionary I currently have:

```
{'abc': ['123', '456'], 'def': ['789', '101112']}
```

instead of appending the values I want to add them to the original value so that it looks like:

```
{'abc': ['579'], 'def': ['101901']}
```

My current code is:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
infile = open('test.csv','r')
lines = infile.readlines()[2:-1]
for item in lines:
    key, value = [a.strip() for a in item.split(' ')]
    d[key].append(value)
```

Comment: why would you want single-element lists that contain strings that are integers? why wouldn't you want {'abc': 579, 'def': 101901}?

Answer (score 2):

```
d = defaultdict(list)
infile = open('test.csv','r')
lines = infile.readlines()[2:-1]
for item in lines:
    key, value = [a.strip() for a in item.split(' ')]
    if key in d:
        d[key][0] = str(int(d[key][0]) + value)
    else:
        d[key].append(str(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = defaultdict(list)
with open('test.csv', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile.readlines()[2:-1]:
        key, value = [a.strip() for a in item.split(' ')]
        d[key] = str(int(d[key] + value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is version using default python `dict`:

```
d = dict()
infile = open('test.csv', 'r')
lines = infile.readlines()[2:-1]
for line in lines:
    k, v = [i.strip() for i in line.split(' ')]
    if k in d:
        d[k] = [str(int(d[k][0]) + int(v))]
    else:
        d[k] = [v]
print d
```